# Enabling number on iterm2 tabs

Tags: terminal, iterm2

How does one achieve the following effects in iTerm2. Displaying the number on each tab of the terminal. This was seen in Michael Hartl's ROR tutorial and was wondering how I could replicate that on my own development setup

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your iTerm2 profile, check that you DID NOT tick the following settings

```
Appearance -> Hide tab number and tab close button
```

You should see the tab number if you don't tick that option

Comment: Wow! After close to 6 months somebody answered the question! Thank you very much!